# any java libs to filter attributes from one object?

Tags: java, object, filter, field

is there any java libs for filter/griddle attributes of a big object, generate a new small object has less attributes?
i need to extract some fields from one object.

thanks

Comment: Are the types already existing? How is the mapping to be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter/griddle attributes"

Comment: I mean I have one object obj1 has 4 attributes(int a1, string a2, int a3, string a4), I want to use some configuration driven java method to generate a new object ob2 which has 2 attributes(a1, a2).   any existent library exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the BeanUtils library. Specifically, [this method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)